# phonegap geolocation in the background

Tags: geolocation

we are looking for a solution to track our business iPads using HTML5. Is there a way to look the geolocation by using i.e. phonegap in a webapp which is maybe inactive (running in the background - still in the task manager)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try out my Phonegap 3.x plugin for iOS and Android.  I'm currently working pretty hard on the Android side, porting features fleshed out in iOS, like stationary-region monitoring, auto-scaling distance-filter.  stop-detection.

I'm a noob with Obj-C and Java but improving :)

The plugin has a debug mode where it emits sounds for its life-cycle events (location change, exit stationary-region, and more)

https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Yes - normal phonegap implementation is working in the background.

```
// onSuccess Callback
//   This method accepts a `Position` object, which contains
//   the current GPS coordinates
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                        '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Options: retrieve the location every 3 seconds
//
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { frequency: 3000 });
```

You can send me a private massage if you have further questions.

Comment: This does NOT work .. GPS watching will be turned off when putting the app in the background, it will be turned on when you launch the app again.